# Hybris commerce - Product restriction and category restriction for user group on site

Tags: sap-commerce-cloud

I have a case where a particular group "milkUG" can only view certain category "milk" on site

Ex:
Say I have a product 1201 it has category "milk" and category "size_500ml" is assigned to it
Sku: 1201
Category: "milk" visible only to "milkUG" group and "size_500ml" visible to "customergroup"

I have enabled personalization rules and thereby when I hit /c/milk it shows 404 page which is fine
but when I access /p/1201 or /c/size_500ml the product is visible which shouldn't be the case

**Ultimately product should not be visible but here out of two, one category is restricted by user group visibility but other is visible and hence the product is visible which is the problem.**

I believe Hybris should have a solution out of the box. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SearchRestriction did solve this

```
INSERT_UPDATE SearchRestriction;code[unique=true];principal(uid)[unique=true];restrictedType(code)[unique=true];active;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can check [Rauf Aliev blog post](https://hybrismart.com/2019/05/20/product-whitelisting-blacklisting-large-volumes-in-commerce-cloud/) about listing restriction, it has more detail and solution.